# AutoFixture multiple customization wont work

Tags: c#, autofixture

AutoFixture will not work with register and additional customize call. If I do only one of the two, it works. The whole behavior of customize feature is hard to understand for me. Is this works as designed?

Goal: Use the greediest constructor AND `OmitAutoProperties` for special class.

```
public interface IDataProvider { }
public class FileDataProvider : IDataProvider {}
public class TestClass
{
      public TestClass() : this (new FileDataProvider()) { }
      public TestClass(IDataProvider dataProvider) { } // should be used from AutoFixture
}

[Fact]
public void Method_State_Result()
{
      var fixture = new Fixture();

      fixture.Register(() => fixture.Build<TestClass>().OmitAutoProperties().Create());
      var dc1 = fixture.Create<TestClass>(); // working

      fixture.Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
      fixture.Customizations.Add(new MethodInvoker(new GreedyConstructorQuery()));

      var dc2 = fixture.Create<TestClass>(); // crash with "AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from System.SByte*, most likely because it has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type"
      var dc3 = fixture.Create<TestClass>();
}
```

A workaround would be to do the registration like this. But feels not like the right solution...

```
fixture.Register(() => new Fixture().Build<TestClass>().OmitAutoProperties().Create());
```

Comment: Good question. I've always wondered this.

Comment: I have found a workaround for my problem but still curious how some other solutions could look like.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, then the easiest option is to provide a custom factory that uses a specimen builder.

```cs
fixture.Customize<TestClass>(c => c
    .FromFactory(new MethodInvoker(new GreedyConstructorQuery()))
    .OmitAutoProperties());
```

Here is a sample test.

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass() : this(new FileDataProvider())
    {
    }

    public TestClass(IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        DataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public IDataProvider DataProvider { get; }
}

[Fact]
public void FooTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    fixture.Customize<TestClass>(c => c
        .FromFactory(new MethodInvoker(new GreedyConstructorQuery()))
        .OmitAutoProperties());

    var mockProvider = fixture.Freeze<IDataProvider>();
    var testObject = fixture.Create<TestClass>();

    Assert.Null(testObject.SomeString);
    Assert.Same(mockProvider, testObject.DataProvider);
}
```